# Determine the correct size type for the result of a binary operation between two vector types or one vector type and a scalar type

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, type-traits

Please consider the following code snippet:

```
template<class E>
class vector_expression {};

template<class Tuple>
class vector
    : public vector_expression<vector<Tuple>>
{
public:
    using value_type = typename Tuple::value_type;
    using size_type = typename Tuple::size_type;
};

namespace detail
{
    template<class E>
    constexpr bool is_vector_expression_v = std::is_base_of_v<vector_expression<std::decay_t<E>>, std::decay_t<E>>;

    template<class E, class = void>
    struct value_type { using type = std::decay_t<E>; };
    template<class E>
    struct value_type<E, std::enable_if_t<is_vector_expression_v<E>>> { using type = typename std::decay_t<E>::value_type; };

    template<class E>
    using value_type_t = typename value_type<E>::type;

    template<class E1, class E2, class BinaryOperation>
    class vector_binary_operation
    {
    public:
        using value_type = std::result_of_t<BinaryOperation(value_type_t<E1>, value_type_t<E2>)>;
    };
}
```

`E1` and `E2` might be either a type derived from `vector_expression` or any type used as the `value_type` of a `vector`.

The `vector` type corresponding to the result of a `vector_binary_operation` needs to be chosen with care. It makes perfectly sense that its `value_type` equals the type of the result of the invoked `BinaryOperation`.

However, the correct `size_type` is harder to deduce. Here's what I want to do:

- If `E1` and `E2` are `vector_expression`s, then let `size_type = std::conditional_t<
  std::numeric_limits<typename std::decay_t<E1>::size_type>::max() <
  std::numeric_limits<typename std::decay_t<E2>::size_type>::max(),
  typename std::decay_t<E1>::size_type,
  typename std::decay_t<E2>::size_type>>>;`
- If `E1` or `E2` (say `E1`) is not a `vector_expression`, then let `size_type = typename std::decay_t<E2>::size_type`

It won't happen that `E1` and `E2` are both no `vector_expression`s. However, (take that as a secondary question) should I add a `class = std::enable_if_t<is_vector_expression_v<E1> || is_vector_expression_v<E2>>` to the template parameter list of `vector_binary_operation`?

The main question is: How can I define `size_type` as described above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to do that is with additional traits or enrich your current traits:

You may make a traits which give `sizeof(E1::size_type)` for `vector_expression` and `0` for

```
template<class E, class = void>
struct value_type {
    using type = std::decay_t<E>;
    using size_type = char; // or better some dummy type
    static constexpr std::size_t size = 0; // To be the minimal size
};
template<class E>
struct value_type<E, std::enable_if_t<is_vector_expression_v<E>>> {
    using type = typename std::decay_t<E>::value_type;
    using size_type = typename std::decay_t<E>::size_type;
    static constexpr std::size_t size = std::numeric_limits<size_type>::max();
};
```

And then

```
template<class E1, class E2, class BinaryOperation>
class vector_binary_operation
{
public:
    using value_type = std::result_of_t<BinaryOperation(value_type_t<E1>,
                                                        value_type_t<E2>)>;
    using size_type = std::conditional_t<(value_type<E1>::size < value_type<E2>::size),
                                         typename value_type <E1>::size_type,
                                         typename value_type <E2>::size_type>>>;
};
```

Comment: `value_type::size_type` sounds somehow weird, cause `value_type` and `size_type` are loosely related. So, I think it's better to use a new struct `size_type` with members `type` and `max`. However, thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: `size` in the specialization should have type `size_type`. [*std::size_t can store the maximum size of a theoretically possible object of any type*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t), but this statement is related to the `sizeof` operator. The `size_type` occurring in a `vector` might be some abstract complicated thing. While that's unusual and unlikely, the code should work in that case too.

Comment: @0xbadf00d: with a renaming to something like `vector_trait_helper`, it might have sense to have all in one `struct`, but I agree that I should have changed name, or create another `struct`.

Comment: For size, I first use `sizeof` before I saw that you use `max()`... But it give you enough information to adjust to you use case :-)

Answer (score 1):

Generally I find that in such cases, it may often be easiest to just define a set of overloads `auto Foo(E1,E2) -> ResultType` to do the actual operation, and then set `vector_binary_operation::size_type = decltype(Foo(E1,E2))`.

In your particular case, you'd have three overloads: for E1, E2 or both being a vector_expression.

In this particular case I see an alternative. Introduce a helper `template<typename T> class sizer { const int max = 0; }` with a specialization `template<typename T> class sizer<vector_expression<T>> { const int max = std::numeric_limits<typename std::decay_t<E1>::size_type>::max() ; }`.

The idea behind this is simple. Your general expression compares two properties from two vector expressions, and picks the type for which the property is greatest. By defining this property to be zero for all other types, all other types rank below your vector_typs and won't get chosen.

Comment: Concerning your first approach: The `size_type` is especially needed in `vector_binary_operation` as the correct type for the indexing `operator[]`. I don't see how I could deduce this type as the result type of an operation `Foo`. Maybe you've got an idea.

Comment: Note that in your second approach, we need to use an `enable_if` solution as presented by [Jarod42](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36549065/547231), cause `E1` are (in general) types derived from `vector_expression`.

Comment: @0xbadf00d: I don't have an idea either; it's your problem domain. The core of that idea is that you have 3 different formula's to calculate a type, depending on the input. By using function overloading, you can use those three different formula's in three function declarations, and then pick the appropriate one. Note that you don't even need to _call_ the function, the function overloading in `decltype(Foo(...))` is all resolved from just the declarations of `Foo`.

Comment: As for the template specialization, it doesn't require `enable_if`. The second template is more specialized than the first, so the first one will not be used when the second one is usable.

Comment: Sure, but the specialization won't be picked for a `vector`. Note that you need to replace `E1` by `T`. Moreover, `max` should be static and you should use a `struct` instead of a `class` (`max` is `private` in your declaration). Last but not least, `max` in the specialization should be of type `size_type`, cause you don't know if the value of `numeric_limits::max()` can be stored in an `int`.